# Compiling with TL2015 doesn't work

Tags: texlive, texstudio

I wanted to install TeXLive shortly. But when I start my TeXStudio Editor and I try to compile a minimal example, the following failure occurs:

```
Prozess gestartet: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "document".tex 

Cannot get a temporary directory after five iterations ... sorry! at d:\TeXlive\2015\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\fmtutil.pl line 334. 

fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order): fmtutil: d:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes: fmtutil: c:/users/bastian/.texlive2015/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf 

D:\TeXlive\2015\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:663: command failed with exit code 2: perl.exe d:\TeXlive\2015\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\fmtutil.pl --byfmt pdflatex 

Running the command D:\TeXlive\2015\bin\win32\fmtutil.exe 

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt The command name is D:\TeXlive\2015\bin\win32\mktexfmt 

Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)
```

(It is German-English mix, `Prozess gestartet` means `process started` and `Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)` means `process ended with error(s)`.)

I really don't have any idea how to solve this problem. I uninstalled TL2014. I did not receive any errors or problems during the installation of TL2015, everything went fine. Renaming `c:/users/bastian/.texlive2015` to `c:/users/bastian/.texlive2015incase` is not possible: it says that I have to enter a filename when I wanted to add the "...incase".

Comment: that error message has come up before eg http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.live/37546  but not seen a conclusive description of the cause or what to do

Comment: This does not solve (or even identify the cause of) the problem, but maybe you can just use the [portable TL edition](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#tlportable) or the [portable MiKTeX](http://www.miktex.org/portable/) to compile your thesis (Good luck for the thesis!).

Comment: Was the installation successful or did you receive warnings or reports of errors?

Comment: Try renaming `c:/users/bastian/.texlive2015 ` to `c:/users/bastian/.texlive2015incase`. I say rename it because I know nothing about Windows. On a Unix-ish system, deleting it would be safe. I am reasonably confident that must be true here as well, but not confident enough to recommend it. However, if you rename it and I'm wrong, you can just name it back what it was and I will only have wasted a few minutes of your time - not wreaked havoc on your system. The response in the thread David linked suggests it is a permissions issue. The idea is to force recreation of the temporary directories.

Comment: i did not receive any errors or problems during the installation. everthing went fine. problem still not solved.
I cant rename it, it says, i have to enter a filename when i wanted to add the "...incase"

Comment: I had the same error - But my .texlive2015 was missing completely.

Did you try to rename the folder with command line, or just with explorer?